# Change class of ancestor from child component in Angular

Tags: angular, sass, bootstrap-5, angular12

I'm using the bootstrap `container` class in my app and because all but one page uses it, I stuck it in the app.component.html file:

```html
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I now have a single page though where I want to use `container-fluid` instead of `container`. Is there any way that the child component can change that class? I tried setting the margin in the child's scss the the `!important` tag but that didn't work. I also tried this to no avail:

```html
::ng-deep :host-context(.container) {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

## Answer

Updated to show the routing solution from Aviad P's comment. Just stick this in the `app.component.ts` file:

```js
readonly #destroy$ = new Subject<void>()
fluid = false

constructor(private readonly router: Router) {
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.#destroy$.next()
    this.#destroy$.complete()
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.pipe(
        filter(x => x instanceof ActivationEnd),
        map(x => (x as ActivationEnd).snapshot.data),
        takeUntil(this.#destroy$)
    ).subscribe(x => {
        this.fluid = x.hasOwnProperty('fluid') ? !!x.fluid : false
    })
}
```

and in your HTML, you'd do this:

```html
<div [ngClass]="{'container': !fluid, 'container-fluid': fluid}">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need a service that will be the communication channel between the component of the route and the main component. That service will have a variable which will decide if the main component is `container` or `container-fluid` and each component can toggle it as they wish.

`container.service.ts`

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ContainerService {
  public fluid = false;
}
```

`app.component.html`

```html
<div [class.container]="!svcContainer.fluid" [class.container-fluid]="svcContainer.fluid">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

`app.component.ts`, 'page-one.component.ts`, ... - inject the service

```js
  constructor(public svcContainer: ContainerService) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great!  I just had to make sure the child that set `fluid` to `true` also implemented `OnDestroy` to set it back to `false`

Comment: You can also make it more automatic by adding a flag to routes which should be fluid, and then subscribing to router navigation events, and in there set the flag on the service appropriately, that way you don't have to inject the service into each and every component.

Comment: Even better.  I updated the question to show the solution with the router watch.